# How to classify Compound Strings?

Tags: computational-linguistics, onomastics, text-classification

My team and I have been working on a project that involves classifying different strings in a text, or more specifically, Wikipedia Infoboxes. For example, *Barack Obama* would be classified as a **Personal Name**, *California* as a **Toponym**, and *1914-1916* would be classified as a **Time Interval**.

However, Wikipedia data is not only vast, but it's also very messy and hard to work with, making our task very difficult.

The issue that we have come across is being able to classify compound strings or lists that contain more than one type of information. We don't want to classify each individual part of the string, but the string as a whole. For example, we have the following strings that we don't know how to classify as a whole:

- *2006, 2007, 2012*

  - Wouldn't classify this as date, date, date.
  - Possibly classify as a **list** since this has the same type of information in a row.
- *Rangana Herath (23)*

  - We wouldn't classify this as Personal Name, Age.
- *Turkish (3.55%) (2002)*
- *Kazakhs reduced from 60% to 38% of the republic's population*

We want to know if there are terms that we could use that would help us classify these compound strings that contain more than one type of information. If so, what are these terms or names that we could use to classify these compound strings? How should we classify the examples provided above?

Comment: There's an unlimited number of ways to classify all of these things. It all depends on what your purposes are.

Comment: The simple answer is that there is no term that covers any or all of these strings of words. Feel free to make up any term you want, and the marketplace of ideas will determine whether anyone adopts your terminology.